# Update table.column with another table.column with common joined column

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hit a speed bump, trying to update some column values in my table from another table.

This is what is supposed to happen when everything works

> 15. Correct all the city, state entries in tblWADonations by creating an update statement that moves the zip city from the joined city/state zip field to the tblWADonations city state

TBL NAME    |   COLUMN NAMES

1. tblZipcodes with zip,city,State
2. tblWADonations  with zip,oldcity,oldstate

This is what I have so far:

```
 UPDATE    tblWADonations
 SET              oldCity = tblZipCodes.city, oldState = tblZipCodes.state
 FROM         tblWADonations INNER JOIN
                  tblZipCodes ON tblWADonations.zip = tblZipCodes.zip
 Where oldCity <> tblZipcodes.city;
```

There seems to be easy ways to do this online but I am overlooking something. Tried this by hand and in editor this is what it kicks back.

> Msg 8152, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
>   String or binary data would be truncated.
>   The statement has been terminated.

Please include a sql statement or where I need to make the edit so I can mark this post as a reference in my favorites. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your table definitions to ensure that the maximum size of the `VARCHAR` fields you are trying to update match up. The error you are seeing indicates that the size of the field being updated/compared is smaller than the data you are trying to update it with.

As a rule of thumb, try and make sure than any similar fields (i.e. `city` and `oldCity`) are identically sized to avoid issues like this in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the column definitions for both tables, in particular compare the columns you are trying to copy to each other - this should give you a hint as to why the error is cropping up.

As this is marked homework, I will leave my answer at that.

Comment: thanks for the help guys sometimes error messages can be so cryptic you don't know where to start!